# Format comma seperated list of dates in python

Tags: python, list, datetime, date, dictionary

I've got a list of dates (datetimes):

```
>>> print str(range)
[datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 15, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 16, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 17, 0, 0)]
```

and I'd like to format them as "%d/%m/%Y" and comma separate them, ie:

> 15/12/2011, 16/12/2011, 17/12/2011

At the moment I'm using map to run strftime on each of the dates like so:

```
>>> string = ", ".join(map(lambda x: x.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"), range))
>>> print string
```

which outputs:

> 15/12/2011, 16/12/2011, 17/12/2011

Ta dah!

It's not the easiest to read, but it works. Is it efficient? Is it pythonic? (does that matter?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map()` is considered deprecated (although there are those that will argue otherwise).

```
", ".join(x.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") for x in daterange)
```

Comment: Why "_`map()` is considered deprecated_"? Could you provide a source?

Comment: I'm going to argue otherwise on that point, simply because `map()` still exists in Python 3.2 with no deprecation notice. However, I agree that the "map-with-lambda" pattern is better implemented with a comprehension or generator.

Comment: @Greg: But it's no longer the same `map()`.

Comment: That's a pretty fine point, since either one would work equally well in the OP's code.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'll use comprehension. Out of interest, do you know if there's any difference in performance?

Comment: That's not a list comprehension, it's a generator expression. It trades the initial cost of generating the list for a per-access cost of generating each element.

Answer (score 0):

why not use list expression?

```
",".join([ date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y") for date in range])
```

yes, map is deprecated, this is in the official documentation, because list expression is better optimized.

Comment: It doesn't say deprecated on the page I'm looking at [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map). Could you show me where you see deprecated?

Comment: OK, i think "deprecated" maybe a little bit too much, sorry for that, "not encouraged" is better for the performance issue. I guess it comes out from [link](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/26234-filter-map-deprecated)